# CSS sticky menu links don't work when menu is stickied

Tags: css, jsfiddle, sticky

[JSFiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/qcb6xnsL/)

I'm trying to make a CSS-only sticky menu (no JavaScript). When you scroll down, hover over menu items no longer works. I'm not sure why not.

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cont2 h1 {
  background: black;
  color: lightskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cont2 nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: lightskyblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.cont2 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cont2 nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cont2 nav ul li a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: orange;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
}
```

I'm not posting the HTML here, because it's too much.

Comment: set z-index to the sticky bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `z-index:1;` to class `.sticky-nav`

Here is the updated snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cont2 h1 {
  background: black;
  color: lightskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cont2 nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: lightskyblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.cont2 nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cont2 nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cont2 nav ul li a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: orange;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container cont2">
  <h1> Main Heading </h1>

  <nav class="sticky-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Page One </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Page Two </a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2> LOREM IPSUM </h2>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h2> LOREM IPSUM </h2>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="contact">
    <h2> CONTACT ME </h2>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: @KesavanR who told you that? read here all about z-index and positions https://codeburst.io/z-index-is-not-voodoo-bro-24bbe4d6d997

Comment: @VikasJadhav the link you provide confirm what Kesavan said *This means that Z-index only works on positioned elements.* and sticky is considered positionned because it behave like relative and fixed